# SQLiteConstraintException error message for insert duplicate primary key

Tags: android, sqlite

```
try {
    db.insertOrThrow("savedreports", null, cv);
} catch (SQLException e) {
   Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

If the code above is executed trying to insert duplicate record (same primary key and fields values as well) what error message will the exception give?

"PRIMARY KEY must be unique"
or 
"UNIQUE constraint failed"
or
???

My program will grab some records from a server and then informs the server to delete those records. However sometimes the http request to delete the records fails due to bad connection, hence I would get the same records when I rerequest for the latest records.

I currently insert these records using insertOrThrow, hence when the duplicate records occur, I would like to know exactly the exception thrown it's exactly due to duplicate records (and not due to null column constraint, database connection close or etc).

Answer (score 0):

These constraints are designed to detect programming errors, not runtime errors. Therefore, there is no guaranteed error message.

If you want to check that the key is not a duplicate, you have to do the check yourself.
But if this is the only constraint that can fail, you can INSERT OR IGNORE instead ([insertWithOnConflict()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int)) in Android).